# "Сразу видно разницу" или "сразу видна разница"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать?

Comment: А это без разницы. )))


Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что оба варианта правильные. Всё зависит от того, на чём хочется сделать смысловой акцент. Если акцент нужно сделать на том, что разница есть, и она видна, то эту разницу лучше сделать подлежащим (вариант "сразу видна разница"). Если же самое важное будет дальше, и суть не в самой разнице, а в том, между чем и чем, то лучше всю эту конструкцию, включая саму разницу, сделать дополнением (вариант "сразу видно разницу").

Comment: Кто на ком стоял? (С)
По-моему вы просто запутались, пытаясь сказать хоть что-то осмысленное. Во всяком случае подобную семантику (сразу-потом и проч.) углядеть здесь никоим образом невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш комментарий бесконечно обогатил мой ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Ещё бы обогатить ваше умение выражаться попонятнее.

Comment: Обещаю, что буду упорно работать в этом направлении. И если мне удастся достичь хоть какого-то прогресса, то знайте - подтолкнули меня к этому именно вы.

Comment: Да-да, пожалуйста. А то от вас один флуд.